# Introspecting Docker/Kubernetes Runtime to check whether it is a Docker Container or a Container within a POD in Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, azure-aks, aws-fargate, amazon-eks

How can I check whether it is plain vanilla docker container or
a container wrapped in a pod by way of a very simple introspection
during runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kubernetes sets many environment variables inside the container by default. You can check if any of them are set.  eg: `KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST`

```
# kubectl exec -it api-server-594f9684b-jg2d4 env | grep KUBERNETES
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS=443
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=10.96.0.1
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO=tcp
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP=tcp://10.96.0.1:443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR=10.96.0.1
KUBERNETES_PORT=tcp://10.96.0.1:443
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-environment-variables/